# Replacing Image on Woocommerce Shop Page using hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to use hooks to remove the product thumbnail from the shop/catalog page in Woocommerce and then replace it with my own custom image.

**`add_action`** works as expected and displays the text, but the **`remove_action`** does not remove the product thumbnail. 
[Here is the page related web site page.](http://preview.jx6tbi4lxxrh33dig2ue7ze4otysc3disodyluk0mq60qkt9.box.codeanywhere.com/shop/)

What I am doing wrong?

Below is the code I'm using:

```
// Remove product images from the shop loop
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

//Add custom code to replace product thumbnail
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumb', 10 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumb' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumb() {
        echo "testing";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to fire this using **`woocommerce_init`** hook and this way it just works.

Here is the code:

```
function replacing_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    // Remove product images from the shop loop
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
    // Adding something instead
    function wc_template_loop_product_replaced_thumb() {
        echo "TEST TEST";
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_template_loop_product_replaced_thumb', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'replacing_template_loop_product_thumbnail');
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and fully functional.

Comment: Thanks, I know this should work, but unfortunately can't get it to. I'm beginning to think it may have something to do with the theme.

Comment: Yep, turns out the Avada theme has their own function called avada_woocommerce_thumbnail. Now I'm up and running!